# MongoDB currentOp size limit

Tags: mongodb, limit

I'm getting a lot of messages like
`{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-24T09:28:43.634+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4760300, "ctx":"conn2065694","msg":"Gathering currentOp information, operation of size {size} exceeds the size limit of {limit} and will be truncated.","attr":{"size":60396,"limit":**51200**}}`
But I don't understand what's the "limit" shoots here / can't match current settings

51200 seems 50K

```
# mongo --eval  "db.adminCommand( { getParameter: '*' })" | grep  50
    "allowRolesFromX509Certificates" : true,
        "MONGODB-X509",
    "internalInsertMaxBatchSize" : 500,
    "internalQueryCacheMaxEntriesPerCollection" : 5000,
    "internalQueryCacheSize" : 5000,
    "journalCommitInterval" : 500,
    "maxTenantMigrationDonorServiceThreadPoolSize" : 50,
    "maxTimeMSForHedgedReads" : 150,
    "migrationLockAcquisitionMaxWaitMS" : 500,
    "mongosShutdownTimeoutMillisForSignaledShutdown" : 15000,
    "replBatchLimitOperations" : 5000,
    "reshardingCriticalSectionTimeoutMillis" : 5000,
    "reshardingOplogBatchLimitOperations" : 5000,
    "scramSHA256IterationCount" : 15000,
    "shutdownTimeoutMillisForSignaledShutdown" : 15000,
    "tenantApplierBatchSizeOps" : 500,
    "tenantMigrationDisableX509Auth" : false,
    "tlsX509ExpirationWarningThresholdDays" : 30,
    "wiredTigerFileHandleCloseMinimum" : 250,
```

I don't see here something related to mentioned limit. And there is no 51 or 512 values at all
So the question is: what value is exceeded and can it be increased?